# Add second lookup to exising ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following function which looks up documents in a database and loops through the results to form a list of links. I need to add another nested lookup to find the DATE_INPUT field--which resides in another table--based on the CNT_DOCUMENT_ID field, add it to the results, then sort them in descending order to find the last three document added. This will require another API call with Payload and Params but I'm not sure how to place the second call and append the results to the first lookup. Here's the code:

```
function getNewsDocuments(strCategoryID) {
    getDomainRootCat(); //looks up locreg
    var CategoryId = "";
    CategoryId = strCategoryID;

    var strPayload = "<Parameters><RequestContext><RequestUserId>ML.BASE.USR.Administrator</RequestUserId><RequestLocaleId>" + locreg + "</RequestLocaleId><RequestRegionId>" + locreg + "</RequestRegionId></RequestContext>" +
        "<Payload1>" +
        "<USR_LMS_USER_ID>ML.BASE.USR.Administrator</USR_LMS_USER_ID><CNTCTGY_CATEGORY_ID>" + CategoryId + "</CNTCTGY_CATEGORY_ID><strIncludeSubCategories>T</strIncludeSubCategories>" +
        "<SearchType>ML.BASE.DV.SearchAllWords</SearchType><TABLE_NAME>CONTENT_SEARCH</TABLE_NAME><CNT_CONTENT_TYPE_ID>ML.BASE.DOCUMENT</CNT_CONTENT_TYPE_ID>" +
        "</Payload1></Parameters>";  

    var strParams = "strCall=AdHocCall&strClassName=" + escape('BusinessLogic.ContentManagement') + "&strMethodName=GenericSearch&strPayload=" + escape(strPayload);
    var list = "<ul style=\"list-style: none; text-indent: -1.2em;\" class=\"newsupdates-list\" id=\"newsupdates-" + strCategoryID + "\">";

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      async: false,
      data: strParams,
      url: "/AJAXUtilities.aspx",      
      success: function(msg){
        msg = $.createXMLDocument(msg);      

        $(msg).find('CONTENT_SEARCH').each(function(){

            if ($(this).find("CNT_AVAILABLE").text() == "T") {
            var objid = $(this).find("CNT_CONTENT_ID").text();
            var title = $(this).find("CNT_TITLE").text();

            if (title.length >= 40){
            var trimtitle = title.substring(0,39);
            list = list.concat("<li><a href=\"/MyOptions.aspx?id=" + objid + "\">" + trimtitle +"...</a></li><hr>");    
            }else{
            list = list.concat("<li><a href=\"/MyOptions.aspx?id=" + objid + "\">" + title +"</a></li><hr>");
            }

            }
        });

      }
    });

    list = list.concat("</ul>");
    list = list.concat("<br /><a href=\"\">View previous updates>></a>");   
    $("#newscatlist").append(list);
    return list;

}
```

UPDATE: I was able to get a look at the XML that is created from the API call and there's a sequential ID number that I can use instead of making the second call to get the date. I've been trying to get the descending sorting to work but can't seem to get it right. Here's the updated ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  async: false,
  data: strParams,
  url: "/Kview/CustomCodeBehind/Base/Utilities/AJAXUtilities.aspx",      
  success: function(msg){
    msg = $.createXMLDocument(msg);      
    var li_count = 0;
    $(msg).find('CONTENT_SEARCH').each(function(){
        if ($(this).find("CNT_AVAILABLE").text() == "T") {
            var seq = $(this).find("CNT_SEQ_ID").text();
            seq.sort(function(a, b){
                return (parseInt($(a).node("CNT_SEQ_ID")) - parseInt($(b).node("CNT_SEQ_ID")));
                seq.each(function(){
                    var objid = $(this).find("CNT_CONTENT_ID").text();
                    var title = $(this).find("CNT_TITLE").text();
                    if (title.length >= 40){

                    var trimtitle = title.substring(0,39);
                    list = list.concat("<li><a href=\"/Kview/CustomCodeBehind/Base/Content/MyOptions.aspx?id=" + objid + "\">" + trimtitle +"...</a></li><hr>");    
                    }else{
                    list = list.concat("<li><a href=\"/Kview/CustomCodeBehind/Base/Content/MyOptions.aspx?id=" + objid + "\">" + title +"</a></li><hr>");
                    }
                    li_count = li_count+1;
                    if (li_count == 3) {
                    return false;
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
  }
});
list = list.concat("</ul>");
list = list.concat("<br /><a href=\"\">View previous clinical updates>></a>");  
$("#newscatlist").append(list);
return list;
```

Here's the XML structure generated by the API call:

```
  <CONTENT_SEARCH>
    <CNT_SEQ_ID>29056</CNT_SEQ_ID>
    <CNT_CONTENT_ID>394414E8962345FAA04C01EF09E1E97E</CNT_CONTENT_ID>
    <CNT_CONTENT_TYPE_ID>ML.BASE.DOCUMENT</CNT_CONTENT_TYPE_ID>
    <CNT_TITLE>News Document5</CNT_TITLE>
    <CNT_DESCRIPTION>News Document4</CNT_DESCRIPTION>
    <CTYP_CONTENT_LAUNCH_TYPE>Document</CTYP_CONTENT_LAUNCH_TYPE>
    <CNT_AVAILABLE>T</CNT_AVAILABLE>
    <CTYPLCL_DISPLAY_NAME>Document</CTYPLCL_DISPLAY_NAME>
    <OBJ_STATUS>T</OBJ_STATUS>
    <CTYP_HAS_SCORE_FLAG>F</CTYP_HAS_SCORE_FLAG>
    <CNT_USER_COST>0</CNT_USER_COST>
    <PERMISSION>1</PERMISSION>
  </CONTENT_SEARCH>
  <CONTENT_SEARCH>
    <CNT_SEQ_ID>29134</CNT_SEQ_ID>
    <CNT_CONTENT_ID>F59863E43FDC4250A662BE6CC35239BD</CNT_CONTENT_ID>
    <CNT_CONTENT_TYPE_ID>ML.BASE.DOCUMENT</CNT_CONTENT_TYPE_ID>
    <CNT_TITLE>News Document6</CNT_TITLE>
    <CNT_DESCRIPTION>news document 6</CNT_DESCRIPTION>
    <CTYP_CONTENT_LAUNCH_TYPE>Document</CTYP_CONTENT_LAUNCH_TYPE>
    <CNT_AVAILABLE>T</CNT_AVAILABLE>
    <CTYPLCL_DISPLAY_NAME>Document</CTYPLCL_DISPLAY_NAME>
    <OBJ_STATUS>T</OBJ_STATUS>
    <CTYP_HAS_SCORE_FLAG>F</CTYP_HAS_SCORE_FLAG>
    <CNT_USER_COST>0</CNT_USER_COST>
    <PERMISSION>1</PERMISSION>
  </CONTENT_SEARCH>
  <CONTENT_SEARCH>
    <CNT_SEQ_ID>29135</CNT_SEQ_ID>
    <CNT_CONTENT_ID>7CB8D290D9C3433797FCB213CCAD7B22</CNT_CONTENT_ID>
    <CNT_CONTENT_TYPE_ID>ML.BASE.DOCUMENT</CNT_CONTENT_TYPE_ID>
    <CNT_TITLE>News Document7</CNT_TITLE>
    <CNT_DESCRIPTION>News Document7</CNT_DESCRIPTION>
    <CTYP_CONTENT_LAUNCH_TYPE>Document</CTYP_CONTENT_LAUNCH_TYPE>
    <CNT_AVAILABLE>T</CNT_AVAILABLE>
    <CTYPLCL_DISPLAY_NAME>Document</CTYPLCL_DISPLAY_NAME>
    <OBJ_STATUS>T</OBJ_STATUS>
    <CTYP_HAS_SCORE_FLAG>F</CTYP_HAS_SCORE_FLAG>
    <CNT_USER_COST>0</CNT_USER_COST>
    <PERMISSION>1</PERMISSION>
  </CONTENT_SEARCH>
```

I need to sort on the CNT_SEQ_ID element, then iterate through the results to create the list items. What am I missing in the sort?

Comment: Start by removing `async : false` and learn how to work with asynchronous code.

Comment: @adeneo How do we know he doesn't need to block for some reason?

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown - because you never need to block, if you do, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @adeneo I would believe that you never need to block if John Resig had not made it so trivial to do so.

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown - jQuery makes a lot of things trivial, you still have to know how to use it, and  when it comes to **Asynchronous** Javascript And XML (ajax), it's supposed to be asynchronous, anything else is nonsense and general ignorance from the developer, with a few exceptions.

Comment: re: async, The piece of code I posted is used multiple times in multiple functions and it works perfectly. It is part of a larger JS file that customizes the behavior of a .net site's home page feed. I didn't write it, I'm just modifying it, so if it works as is, I'm not going to change it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: strParams,
        url: "/AJAXUtilities.aspx",      
        success: function(msg){

            msg = $.createXMLDocument(msg);      

            var li_count = 0;
            var results = [];

            $(msg).find('CONTENT_SEARCH').each(function(){

                if ($(this).find("CNT_AVAILABLE").text() == "T") {
                    var seqText = $(this).find("CNT_SEQ_ID").text();
                    var seqVal = parseInt(seqText);
                    var objidText = $(this).find("CNT_CONTENT_ID").text();
                    var titleText = $(this).find("CNT_TITLE").text();
                    results.push({
                        seq: seqText,
                        seqVal: seqVal,
                        objid: objidText,
                        title: titleText
                    }); 
                    results.sort(function(a, b){
                        return b.seqVal - a.seqVal;
                    });
                }
            });
            var html=[];
            html.push("<ul style=\"list-style: none; text-indent: -1.2em;\" class=\"clupdates-list\" id=\"clupdates-" + strCategoryID + "\">");
            $.each(results, function(){
                if (this.title.length >= 40){
                    var trimtitle = this.title.substring(0,39);
                    html.push("<li><a href=\"/MyOptions.aspx?id=" + this.objid + "\">" + trimtitle +"...</a></li><hr>");
                }else{
                    html.push("<li><a href=\"/MyOptions.aspx?id=" + this.objid + "\">" + this.title +"</a></li><hr>");
                }
                li_count = li_count+1;
                if (li_count == 3) {
                return false;
                }
            });
            html.push("</ul>");
            html.push("<br /><a href=\"/documentssimplesearch.aspx\">View previous clinical updates>></a>");
            $("#clinicalcatlist").append(html.join(''));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the Ajax call out into a function for reuse.

```
function getNewsDocuments(strCategoryID) {
    getDomainRootCat(); //looks up locreg
    var CategoryId = "";
    CategoryId = strCategoryID;

    var strPayload = "<Parameters><RequestContext><RequestUserId>ML.BASE.USR.Administrator</RequestUserId><RequestLocaleId>" + locreg + "</RequestLocaleId><RequestRegionId>" + locreg + "</RequestRegionId></RequestContext>" +
        "<Payload1>" +
        "<USR_LMS_USER_ID>ML.BASE.USR.Administrator</USR_LMS_USER_ID><CNTCTGY_CATEGORY_ID>" + CategoryId + "</CNTCTGY_CATEGORY_ID><strIncludeSubCategories>T</strIncludeSubCategories>" +
        "<SearchType>ML.BASE.DV.SearchAllWords</SearchType><TABLE_NAME>CONTENT_SEARCH</TABLE_NAME><CNT_CONTENT_TYPE_ID>ML.BASE.DOCUMENT</CNT_CONTENT_TYPE_ID>" +
        "</Payload1></Parameters>";  

    var strParams = "strCall=AdHocCall&strClassName=" + escape('BusinessLogic.ContentManagement') + "&strMethodName=GenericSearch&strPayload=" + escape(strPayload);
    var list = "<ul style=\"list-style: none; text-indent: -1.2em;\" class=\"newsupdates-list\" id=\"newsupdates-" + strCategoryID + "\">";

    var result = postAJAXUtilities(strPayload, strParams)

}

function getSomethingElse() {
    var strPayload = "?";
    var strParams = "?";
    var result = postAJAXUtilities(strPayload, strParams)
}

function postAJAXUtilities(strPayload, strParams) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      async: false,
      data: strParams,
      url: "/AJAXUtilities.aspx",      
      success: function(msg){
        msg = $.createXMLDocument(msg);      

        $(msg).find('CONTENT_SEARCH').each(function(){

            if ($(this).find("CNT_AVAILABLE").text() == "T") {
            var objid = $(this).find("CNT_CONTENT_ID").text();
            var title = $(this).find("CNT_TITLE").text();

            if (title.length >= 40){
            var trimtitle = title.substring(0,39);
            list = list.concat("<li><a href=\"/MyOptions.aspx?id=" + objid + "\">" + trimtitle +"...</a></li><hr>");    
            }else{
            list = list.concat("<li><a href=\"/MyOptions.aspx?id=" + objid + "\">" + title +"</a></li><hr>");
            }

            }
        });

      }
    });

    list = list.concat("</ul>");
    list = list.concat("<br /><a href=\"\">View previous updates>></a>");   
    $("#newscatlist").append(list);
    return list;

}
```

This assumes your post processing in the success function is the same. If not, you could always make that a separate function that you pass into the ajax call as well.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I don't see how this helps. The result of the first ajax call gives me what I had originally. What I need is to use the result of the first call to make the second call, then sort and produce the list.

Comment: Then you'll need to factor out the `success` function also.

Comment: So the success function of the first call would contain the second call, and the success function of the second call constructs the list?

Comment: You can do it that way. It would be cleaner to make each success function a named function and pass it like postAJAXUtilities(strPayload, strParams, successFunction). But if it's simpler to understand copying the POST code  with a different success value that will still work.

Comment: updated code with additional info. No need to make the second call, now I just have to sort, but I'm having trouble getting it to work.